# Can't run roslaunch turtlebot_gazebo

Tags: gazebo, roslaunch, turtlebot, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

My problem is very similar to this other question: http://answers.ros.org/question/223792/roslaunch-turtlebot_gazebo-failure/
However it didn't seem like a solution was ever found so I thought I'd better ask my own question to get some answers.

I have installed ros indigo, gazebo, roslaunch packages and the gazebo turtlebot packages, using sudo apt-get.
I have set up my environment using source /opt/ros/indigo/setup.bash.
On the gazebo website I am told to run the turtlebot simulation using:
roslaunch turtlebot_gazebo turtlebot_empty_world.launch

When I run that command I get the following error:

[turtlebot_empty_world.launch] is neither a launch file in package [turtlebot_gazebo] nor is [turtlebot_gazebo] a launch file name
The traceback for the exception was written to the log file

In the question I have linked above the suggested solution was to instead use the command:

roslaunch turtlebot_gazebo turtlebot_world.launch

Running that command gives me a different error:

while processing /opt/ros/indigo/share/turtlebot_bringup/launch/includes/robot.launch.xml:

while processing /opt/ros/indigo/share/turtlebot_bringup/launch/includes/description.launch.xml:

Invalid  tag: Cannot load command parameter [robot_description]: command [/opt/ros/indigo/share/xacro/xacro.py '/opt/ros/indigo/share/turtlebot_description/robots/kobuki_hexagons_asus_xtion_pro.urdf.xacro'] returned with code [1].

Param xml is

The traceback for the exception was written to the log file

I am new to ROS and gazebo and any assistance would be appreciated. I also apologise for not knowing how to properly format my question; if anyone can tell me how to mark the error logs as code sections so that they are more readable I would be grateful.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/258754/can%27t-run-roslaunch-turtlebot_gazebo/) by [UniversityStudent1701](https://answers.ros.org/users/29955/universitystudent1701/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2017-04-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Solved the problem by deleting a custom version of python so that the default version would be used instead

---

Originally posted by [UniversityStudent1701](https://answers.ros.org/users/29955/universitystudent1701/) with karma: 16 on 2017-04-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0